# Merge [x64] into [64bit]?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

How about to merge and synonymize [x64](/questions/tagged/x64) (828) into [64bit](/questions/tagged/64bit) (1,913)? Thanks.

Often they're [used together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x64+64bit).

Comment: Have a look at the 64bit tag wiki to see that this might not be the best of ideas http://stackoverflow.com/tags/64bit/info

Comment: x64 is not the only 64bit architecture available. How about SPARC, MIPS, IA64 and Alpha?

Comment: Why merge them? They are not the same thing. And when they're used together, it might be because the question talks about both.

Comment: @Alenanno: When they're used together, that means that author mixes two terms in one and don't see the difference.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I guess that only less then 1% from all are related to SPARC, MIPS, IA64 and Alpha.

Comment: @abatishchev, I guess that with the adoption of 64-bit computing in ARM processors and the widespread of mobile computing the percentages will look different soon.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Hope so :)

Comment: @abatishchev Not necessarily. It could be, but it's not obvious.

Comment: Meta can be quite harsh sometimes... Is -14 even necessary?

Answer (score 24):

No.

[x64](/questions/tagged/x64) refers to the 64-bit version of the x86 architecture. (also known as x86-64)

[64bit](/questions/tagged/64bit) refers to 64-bit computer architecture. (not necessarily x86)

Comment: Sure, you're right, thanks for pointing that out.